# Cesium: can cesium work with float .tif as terrain tiles?

Tags: gis, terrain, cesiumjs

For now I'm using [cesium-terrain-builder](https://github.com/geo-data/cesium-terrain-builder) for producing terrain tiles in .terrain format, but I wonder can Cesium work with float .tif tiles?

I can't see any information about this in [documentation](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/CesiumTerrainProvider.html)

Comment: have you found any answer for this question ?! can you share your solution if you have. i have same problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you already have GeoTIFFs, check out [tin-terrain](https://github.com/heremaps/tin-terrain), it takes a GeoTIFF and produces a .terrain file, or a collection of tiles, in the [quantized-mesh](https://github.com/CesiumGS/quantized-mesh) format of triagulated integrated networks (TINs).

The cesium-terrain-builder tool produces "[heightmap](https://github.com/CesiumGS/cesium/wiki/heightmap-1.0-terrain-format)" .terrain files, which are a rectangular grid of heights rather than TINs. Cesium will render the heightmap tiles, but certain important functions like Cesium.sampleTerrainMostDetailed seem to work only for TINs.

The authors of tin-terrain wrote a helpful blog post about the advantages of TINs: https://developer.here.com/blog/visualizing-large-scale-terrain-with-open-source-tool-tin-terrain